# get position (index) of td element identified by class name

Tags: jquery

i have this code

```
<tr id="3" class="gradeA odd focus row_selected">
    <td class="center">Kids Footwear 2</td>
    <td class="sorting_1 center focus">200</td>
    <td class="center">50</td>
    <td class="center">200</td>
    <td class="center">30-34</td>
    <td class="center">234-343</td>
    <td class="center">200</td>
    <td class="center">25</td>
    <td class="center">1.23</td>
</tr>
```

i want to fetch the index value of `<td>` element which contains the class `focus`

so if within the `<td>` element the focus class is set on

```
first `<td>` then return 0
second `<td>` then return 1
third `<td>` then return 2
```

and so on.how do i go with this in jQuery?

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method. If you have more than one `tr` element containing a `td` with the `focus` class then you will probably want to make the selector specific to the `tr` you care about:

```
var index = $("td.focus").index();
```

From the jQuery docs:

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is
>   an integer indicating the position of the first element within the
>   jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

**Update** (see comments)

You can use `children` or `find` to get the `td` elements from the `tr`, and then use the above code:

```
var index = tr.find("td.focus").index();
```

Comment: okay little bit of confusion here, i have the `<tr>` elements fetched from a function and assigned to a javascript variable `var tr = $(this).parent();` i need a continuation from here.

Comment: perfect, just as i thought i should be using find() you posted it :), thank you.